# How can you model the quicksort algorithm as a martingale sequence?

Tags: martingales

A sequence of random variables $X_0 , X_1,....,X_n$ is called a martingale sequence if:

$E[X_i | X_0,X_1,....,X$<sub>i-1</sub>$]$ = $X$<sub>i-1</sub>

The text that I am reading from says the following:

Let us analyse quicksort on a fixed n input array and track the running time of quicksort algorithm Q as we go along.
The expected running time varies with the choice of each pivot. Let $P_0,P_1,....,P_n$ be the choices of pivot.
Let $T_0 = E[T_Q]$ be the expected running time of Q. and $T_1$ is the expected running time of Q conditioned on the first pivot choice, $T_2$ is the expected running time of Q conditioned on the first two pivot choices, and so on. In general

$T_i$ = $E [T_Q |P_0 , . . . , P$<sub>i-1</sub>$ ]$ , i ≥ 1

Also $T_n$ = $T_Q$  (I did not understand what this statement even means.)

Hence,
$E[T_i |P_0 , P_1 , P_2 , . . . , Pi−1 ]$ = $T$<sub>i−1</sub> , i > 0
Therefore the quicksort is a martingale.

Can you please explain this proof? Thanks.

Comment: Obviously $T_Q$ depends only on the choices of the pivots $(P_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n-1}$, hence indeed $T_Q=E(T_Q\mid (P_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n-1})=T_n$. Furthermore, for every $i$, $\mathcal F_{i-1}\subseteq\mathcal F_i$, where $\mathcal F_j=\sigma((P_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant j-1})$ hence, by the so-called *tower property*, $E(T_Q\mid \mathcal F_{i-1})=E(E(T_Q\mid \mathcal F_{i})\mid\mathcal F_{i-1})$, that is, $T_{i-1}=E(T_i\mid F_{i-1})$.